# Laptop getting really hot

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, overheating, hybrid-graphics

I have tried numerous solutions but my laptop is still getting really hot running Ubuntu.  I have tried a number of different Linux OS's and they all seem to have this issue.  I am now running Linux mint because I thought it might have some vendor drivers that it would install but it has not helped.

> HP Pavilion dv7 7008tx

```
lspci | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev ff)
```

I have installed nvidia drivers and`Bumblebee nvidia Optimus technology`  already.  The computer runs fine when I boot into Windows so it is not a hardware issue.

Any ideas of how to fix this problem?

Comment: @wie5Ooma not exactly sure.  But it was hot enough to make me hot just using the laptop.  It was quite hot to touch on the bottom of the laptop also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with bumblebee but anyway take a look to these tools: **TLP**, **lm_sensors** and **indicator-cpufreq**. All of them easy to google and handy in use for contolling speed and temperature of your cpu.

And btw I suppose you using latest distro? Because very old distros (with kernel < 2.3x) had problem with pcie_aspm parameter on latest hardware which may cause increasing temperature.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at these tools tonight.  Yes I am using the latest distro.

Comment: I ended up doing this and some other things.  I have not noticed it getting as hot as before.  We will see how it goes.

Comment: @jax please put here output of this command:

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`  
`sysctl -n vm.laptop_mode`  
  
don't be afraid here are commands which just reads data.

Comment: 1 performance
     2 performance
     3 performance
     4 performance
     5 performance
     6 performance
     7 performance
     8 performance
cat: sysctl: No such file or directory
cat: vm.laptop_mode: No such file or directory

Comment: Yep, your cpu is always in higher performance mode.  
Please follow by relative to your distro article after googling by keywords `how to set cpu scaling governor to ondemand`.  
And try `sudo sysctl -n vm.laptop_mode` please.